# SDL Audio Pitch - Playback Rate

Tags: c++, audio, sdl, sdl-2

My goal is to connect the RPM of an engine to the pitch of an sound. I am using SDL as my audio Backend.

So my idea was to sample from the wave buffer quicker than normal. So by trail and error I am now able to pitch my engine sound "step by step".

**Question #1**

If I change this part from:

```
audioBuff +=  1 + pitch * 2;
```

to

```
audioBuff += 2
```

I get just noise. Why? Does this have to do with stereo channels?

**Question #2**

How can I make this a linear pitch? Currently it's a "stepping" pitch.

Here is the full code:

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include <iostream>



void audioCallback(void* userdata, Uint8 *stream, int len);

Uint8 *audioBuff = nullptr;
Uint8 *audioBuffEnd = nullptr;
Uint32 audioLen = 0;
bool quit = false;
Uint16 pitch = 0;

int main()
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0)
        return -1;

    Uint32 wavLen = 0;
    Uint8 *wavBuff = nullptr;
    SDL_AudioSpec wavSpec;

    if(SDL_LoadWAV("test.wav", &wavSpec, &wavBuff, &wavLen) == nullptr)
    {
        return 1;
    } 
    wavSpec.callback = audioCallback;
    wavSpec.userdata = nullptr;
    wavSpec.format = AUDIO_S16;
    wavSpec.samples = 2048;
    audioBuff = wavBuff;
    audioBuffEnd = &wavBuff[wavLen];
    audioLen = wavLen;

    if( SDL_OpenAudio(&wavSpec, NULL) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open audio: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_PauseAudio(0);
    while(!quit)
    {
        SDL_Delay(500);
        pitch ++;

    }

    SDL_CloseAudio();
    SDL_FreeWAV(wavBuff);
    return 0;
}


Uint32 sampleIndex = 0;
void audioCallback(void* userdata, Uint8 *stream, int len)
{
    Uint32 length = (Uint32)len;
    length = (length > audioLen ? audioLen : length);

    for(Uint32 i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(audioBuff > audioBuffEnd)
        {
            quit = true;
            return;
        }
        // why pitch * 2?
        // how to get a smooth pitch?
        stream[i] = audioBuff[0];
        audioBuff +=  1 + pitch * 2;
        fprintf(stdout, "pitch: %u\n", pitch);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "linear pitch"?

Comment: I'm asking the same question myself @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: Can pitch be applied to a SDL_mixer's Mix_Chunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the audio format to `AUDIO_S16`, which is "Signed 16-bit little-endian samples".  Each sample is two bytes, with the first byte being the LSB.  When you read the data in `audioCallback`, you're reading it as bytes (8 bits), then passing those bytes back to something expecting 16 bits.  You're getting noise because of this, and when you use `audioBuff +=2;` you're always reading the LSB of the audio sample, which essentially is noise when used that way.

You should consistently use either 16 bit or 8 bit samples.

Comment: Ok thanks. This is how my callback function now looks like:

`void audioCallback(void* userdata, Uint8 *stream, int len)
{
    Uint32 length = (Uint32)len;
    for(Uint32 i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(audioBuff > audioBuffEnd)
        {
            quit = true;
            return;
        }
        
        stream[i] = audioBuff[0];
        i++;
        stream[i] = audioBuff[1];
        audioBuff += 2 * pitch;
    }
}`